# Temporary buffer: Local or member variable?

Tags: c++

In my class, I have one method which requires a large temporary buffer. I see two ways to implement this:

- The buffer is a local variable and allocated statically on every call of the function:

  `double buf[len];`
- The buffer is a member variable of the class and allocates dynamic memory (On construction or first call)

  `this -> buf = new double[len]`

The first way needs allocation of memory on each call, however, I expect stack allocation to be very fast. The second way defines an additional member variable, which is neither needed by other methods nor persistent between method calls, and therefore does not need to be a member variable.

Which one should I prefer?

Comment: Unless `len` is a compile-time constant expression, the first piece of code is not valid C++.

Comment: this is a micro optimization, but `static` is an option - but not thread safe

Comment: Not just thread-safe but also not recursion-safe. It generally can never appear in the call stack in 2 places at once.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I have several such allocations with non-static lengths in my code and it works. I'm not very experienced with C++, so I do not see what's not valid there?

Comment: @Michael Maybe your compiler supports Variable Length Arrays. That not standard C++, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What options you have depends on a few questions:

1. Is the function (potentially indirectly) recursive?
2. Is `len` known at compile time?
3. Can the function be called by multiple threads concurrently? On the same object, on different objects, not at all?

If the function is not recursive, you can use a `static` local variable. If `len` is a compile-time constant, `static double buf[len];` will do. For a run-time value of `len`, use `static std::vector<double> buf(len);` instead. If concurrent calls are possible, add `thread_local` to the declaration.

For a recursive function, you have to use a non-static local variable. If `len` is known at compile time, this will certainly be very fast (it's just stack manipulation). If it's a runtime value, you'll either have to accept dynamic allocation on each call (e.g. `std::vector<double> buf(len);`), or create a memory pool of some sort.

Comment: +1 I think this answer sums up the raised questions (and proposed answers) quite nicely.

Answer (score 2):

There's a third option, which is to use `std::vector` with static storage:

```
static std::vector<double> buf( len );
```

This doesn't require `len` to be a compile time constant and IIRC C++11 guarantees that the initialization of `buf` is thread-safe (in C++03 it wasn't guaranteed though). Of course, actually *using* the buffer won't be thread-safe: you'll either need some sort of synchronization mechanism (e.g. a mutex) or allocate the vector using thread-local storage (e.g. on the stack or via some TLS implementation).

Answer (score 1):

**If the buffer length is constant**

Is thread-safety an issue? If so then go for putting it on the stack as a non-static local variable.

If thread safety is not an issue (and you are not using this function recursively) then I would recommend a static local variable. The static local will not pollute the class with a useless field and not be accessible outside of the scope you intended it for, plus you only have to allocate it once.

**If the buffer length is NOT constant**

See Frerich Raabe's answer. Again note that using it statically has some issues if you are using recursion or expect that your function might be used by more than one thread at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you call this function from multiple threads / recurisvely / any other way then a singleton and these calls need an own buffer use a `vector` local variable:

```
std::vector<double> vec(len);
```

Your local variable solution (`double buf[len];`) will cause a stack overflow if `len` is large enough. (And if `len` is not a compile-time constant, it is not even allowed by the standard, it is only a `g++` extension.)

If you need one buffer per object, use an `std::vector` member variable (This is effectively the same as your second solution but more C++ish and deallocates automatically.)

```
struct X {
    std::vector<double> vec;
    X(int len) : vec(len) {}
}
```

If you are sure that your program will require one single instance of your buffer, use the static version, as int @Frerich's solution.

```
static std::vector<double> buf( len );
```